# How can I put NuGet dependecies into a lib subfolder with dotnet publish?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a larger c# project that uses many DLL's from NuGet packages. When I run dotnet publish, all these DLL's end up together with the EXE and the DLL's of the project in one folder. Is there a possibility to automatically put all these DLL's from NuGet packages into a separate subfolder e.g: "lib"?